# What's wrong with copy-construction of a shared_ptr from an implicit cast?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, type-conversion

Consider this minimal example:

```
#include <memory>

struct B {
  typedef std::shared_ptr<B> Ptr;
};

struct A {
  operator B::Ptr() { // type conversion operator                  <----+
    return std::make_shared<B>();  //                                   |
  }                                //                                   |
};                                 //                                   |
                                   //                                   |
int main() {                       //                                   |
  A* a = new A;                    //                                   |
  B::Ptr{*a}; // copy construction from a's implicit cast to B::Ptr ----+ 
}
```

This innocent copy construction of a `shared_ptr<B>` **fails horribly on g++ 4.6.3 x86_64-linux-gnu** but appears to work for [g++ 4.5](http://ideone.com/RKkgS) (note that the newer version breaks, while the older works!). From what I can tell from the error (see below) g++ 4.6 seems to pass `A` by value, instead of by (r or l) reference.

So, the question is, which is correct and which is broken? Is this behaviour supposed to fail? If so, why?
As far as I understand conversion rules, the implicit cast to `B::Ptr` *should* be attempted at this point, right?

---

<sub>Note: I reduced this example to the bare technical problem, and this code doesn't make sense for any production-system as it stands.</sub>

Here is the precise error:

```
shp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
shp.cpp:17:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<B>::shared_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
shp.cpp:17:12: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:315:2: note: template<class _Alloc, class ... _Args> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:266:17: note: constexpr std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = B, std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:266:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:258:2: note: template<class _Tp1, class _Del> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:253:2: note: template<class _Tp1> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Tp1>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:248:11: note: template<class _Tp1> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const std::weak_ptr<_Tp1>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:236:2: note: template<class _Tp1, class> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:226:7: note: std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&&) [with _Tp = B, std::shared_ptr<_Tp> = std::shared_ptr<B>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:226:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<B>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:218:2: note: template<class _Tp1, class> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:206:2: note: template<class _Tp1> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>&, _Tp*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:184:2: note: template<class _Deleter, class _Alloc> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t, _Deleter, _Alloc)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:165:2: note: template<class _Tp1, class _Deleter, class _Alloc> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(_Tp1*, _Deleter, _Alloc)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:146:2: note: template<class _Deleter> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t, _Deleter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:129:2: note: template<class _Tp1, class _Deleter> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(_Tp1*, _Deleter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:112:11: note: template<class _Tp1> std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(_Tp1*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:103:7: note: std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = B, std::shared_ptr<_Tp> = std::shared_ptr<B>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:103:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘const std::shared_ptr<B>&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:100:17: note: constexpr std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr() [with _Tp = B]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:100:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with `shared_ptr`? What happens if you just create some type and use that in place of `shared_ptr`?

Comment: It works in GCC 4.7.1 (except for the comments ending in backslashes, causing multi-line comment problems) http://liveworkspace.org/code/d7713b217a30dc973795698adfd3c1c8, and I believe it is correct. (I must say, though, I find it a bit misleading to use an `operator B::Ptr` to create a new shared-ptr instance of B, since that instance does not seem to be any kind of _converted form of the A instance_. I trust this is because we are dealing with a reduced example.)

Comment: @NicolBolas: Of course I tried exactly that before posting, but that seemed to work fine. I suspect it has to do with the constructor overloads provided by g++'s implementation of the `shared_ptr`. I'm just at a loss to explain why the older version worked.

Comment: @jogojapan: Indeed, as I noted in the OP, I tried to trim out everything that wasn't essential to the problem.

Comment: This question would be clearer if you gave a custom simplified smart-pointer class instead of shared_ptr. Your code seems to work fine for me using 4.7.0 on MinGW.  Without seeing the specific implementation of shared_ptr, it's hard to say definitively 'this is right' or 'this is wrong'.  Regarding the issue, it sounds like gcc can't find a constructor for shared_ptr<T>&, which I assume is the type of your operator. There is a constructor for const shared_ptr<T> & tho...maybe try defining operator B::Ptr() const{...}?

Comment: @Rollie: But `a` is mutable, why wouldn't the mutating operator be eligible? If I use a custom type instead of a `shared_ptr` I cannot reproduce the issue. *That*'s the question. Would the definition of my `std::shared_ptr` help?

Comment: Have you tried `B::Ptr({*a});` or `B::Ptr(*a);`? (mat be the parser can be fooled ...)

Comment: @bitmask: you can reproduce this with a custom type; start with the full shared_ptr impl, and just start deleting sections that don't matter, and you will be left with something readable. a is mutable, but I don't believe parameter deduction logic will ever say "I expect an A, but I've been given a C. C can be cast to a B, and B can be cast to an A, so we'll do that".  At most, I seem to recall it only does a single cast. If it requires more, it fails.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: If I use `()` braces I have to change the expression slightly as it would be a (re-)declaration of `a` otherwise. So, `(B::Ptr(*a))` compiles while `(B::Ptr{*a})` gives the same errors as above.

Comment: @Rollie: It *should* expect a `B::Ptr const&` and it is given an `A&&`. `A&&` can be converted to `B::Ptr` so I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @Rollie: Throwing out stuff from `shared_ptr` doesn't change anything, as there already seems to be missing something in the `std` version. I get the same error with a different namespace.

Comment: @bitmask rolling your own version of the class would just simplify investigation. I take back what I said earlier though, this looks like 4.6.3 is just wrong. *a should be cast (using the user defined operator) to a `B::Ptr &&`, which should bind to the `const & Ptr` constructor without issue. If not, I'm very curious to hear the correct answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is incorrect under the current version of the standard (I'm looking at post-standard draft n3376).

The rules for list-initialization specify:

> #### 13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization [over.match.list]
>
> 1 - When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized [...]:
>
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

However, when overload resolution is applied to the copy constructor of `B::Ptr` taking the single parameter `const std::shared_ptr<B> &`, the argument list is `(*a)`, consisting of a single element of type *lvalue* `A`; overload resolution is not permitted to consider the conversion function `A::operator B::Ptr`:

> #### 13.3.3.1 Implicit conversion sequences [over.best.ics]
>
> 4 - However, when considering the argument of a constructor or user-defined conversion function that is a candidate [...] by 13.3.1.7 [...] when the initializer list has exactly one element and a conversion to some class X or reference to (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) X is considered for the first parameter of a constructor of X [...], only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered.

So g++-4.6 is correct to reject this code; g++-4.7.2 unfortunately accepts it, which is incorrect.

The correct way to write this would be to use direct-initialization (`B::Ptr(*a)`) or a `static_cast<B::Ptr>`.

The restriction on the allowable conversions can be traced to paper [n2672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm), although in that paper the paragraph 13.3.3.1p4 only applies to *the argument of a user-defined conversion function*.  The additional restriction on constructors was added in [defect 978](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n3006.html#978):

> #### 978. Incorrect specification for copy initialization
>
> 13.3.3.1 [over.best.ics] paragraph 4 says,
> [...]
> This is not quite right, as this applies to constructor arguments, not just arguments of user-defined conversion functions.

The current wording of 13.3.3.1p4 can be traced to the seminal [defect 84](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#84), which introduced the "*common-law rule that only a single user-defined conversion will be called to do an implicit conversion*".

I'm a bit uneasy about this answer; I've asked [Is it possible to invoke a user-defined conversion function via list-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677711/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-user-defined-conversion-function-via-list-initializat) to see if anyone can clarify the intent of the standard here.

Comment: That quote doesn't really address the question at hand. It talks about falling back to non-initiaizer-list constructors after failing to find an initializer-list constructor. But the question at hand is whether it should consider the conversion operator after *also* failing to find a non-initializer-list constructor.

Comment: @fgp Conversion operators are considered when resolving a constructor call; see above.

Comment: @fgp it gets more interesting; per 13.3.3.1p4 your example is not allowed, although it's a rather strange result.